# PayPal later payment behavior and next_billing_date value

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I am working on a PayPal Subscription integration. Please consider the following scenario:

Suppose, I have subscribed to a service with successful a payment. My `next_billing_date` was on the 1st of February 2023, 10 AM GMT. The payment has failed for some reason. And according to [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/payment-failure-retry/#link-paymentfailures) the payment will be retired after 5 days, that is on 5th February 2023. Say on that try the payment became successful and the subscription continues.

Now my question is: **what will be the `next_billing_date` for that subscription after the payment? Will the date be 1st March 2023 or 5th March 2023?**

Is there any tool from PayPal to simulate the scenario(like Stripe's test clock)?

Answer (score 1):

The next billing date will be 1st March 2023

This is [documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/payment-failure-retry/).

Comment: Thank you @preston-phx for the response. Is there any documentation or article from PayPal or any other sources for future reference?